# using XML in the Blender Game Engine

Tags: scripting

i've been experimenting with the BGE and i'm a beginner programmer. I was wondering if their was a way to apply a texture to an object that could be read from an XML file, for the purpose of making a billboard with a changable display? if anyone could give me some help as where to start i'd appreciate it.

Comment: You might be able to parse it with python, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing XML is [very simple](http://www.diveintopython3.net/xml.html) in Python3. You can use the built-in `xml` module for that.

To bind the data to a texture is slightly more complicated, but it can be done too using Blender Game Engine's [videotexture module](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_62_1/bge.texture.html).